# Cannot upgrade to v12 due to sql_identifier data type

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, upgrade

I am attempted to upgrade Postgres 11.8 to 12.3 on an AWS RDS instance. The upgrade fails with the following error:

> Your installation contains the "sql_identifier" data type in user tables
> and/or indexes.  The on-disk format for this data type has changed, so this
> cluster cannot currently be upgraded.  You can remove the problem tables or
> change the data type to "name" and restart the upgrade.
> A list of the problem columns is in the file:
> tables_using_sql_identifier.txt

I do not have access to this file. I believe it is not available to AWS users. I can find the sql_identifier columns with the following:

```
SELECT 
atttypid::regtype, *
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'information_schema.columns'::regclass
ORDER  BY attnum
```

I can update all of the columns to be of type "name" but changing the `information_schema` tables seems aggressive and I cannot find any information about this error anywhere on the internet. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: information_schema doesn't have **user** tables (or shouldn't) and so should not need to be changed.  Your query is listing all columns in one particular table, not all columns of one particular type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the columns with that type outside of information_schema.  Information_schema is not user tables, they are system tables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM pg_attribute 
  join pg_class on attrelid=oid 
  join pg_namespace on relnamespace=pg_namespace.oid 
WHERE atttypid::regtype::text like '%sql_identifier' 
  and nspname!='information_schema'
```