# How to resolve The instance could not be upgraded because the 'reg*' data type is used in user tables?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, datatypes, upgrade

I tried to upgrade a Postgres DB Engine from 11.12 to 13.3 on AWS via the admin console in the browser. But the upgrade could not be performed, the error/pg_upgrade_precheck.log shows this message.

> The instance could not be upgraded from 11.12.R1 to 13.3.R1 because of
> following reasons. Please take appropriate action on databases that
> have usages incompatible with requested major engine version upgrade
> and try again.
>
> - Following usages in database '[mydbname]' need to be corrected before upgrade:
>
> -- The instance could not be upgraded because the 'reg*' data type is used in user tables. Please remove all usages of 'reg*' data types and
> try again.

I checked the AWS RDS upgrade guide and it [mentions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.MajorVersion.Process) this check specifically. It describes to run this query to check that there are no uses of unsupported reg* data types. Problem is, when I run it it returns 0, meaning that there would be no uses of unsupported reg* data types.

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n, pg_catalog.pg_attribute a 
  WHERE c.oid = a.attrelid 
      AND NOT a.attisdropped 
      AND a.atttypid IN ('pg_catalog.regproc'::pg_catalog.regtype, 
                         'pg_catalog.regprocedure'::pg_catalog.regtype, 
                         'pg_catalog.regoper'::pg_catalog.regtype, 
                         'pg_catalog.regoperator'::pg_catalog.regtype, 
                         'pg_catalog.regconfig'::pg_catalog.regtype, 
                         'pg_catalog.regdictionary'::pg_catalog.regtype) 
      AND c.relnamespace = n.oid 
      AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

I also found [this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271672/cannot-upgrade-to-v12-due-to-sql-identifier-data-type). That gave me 1 user tabel with 2 columns. I removed that table, but the upgrade process still is not working and gives the same error messages as before.

How can I otherwise find uses of unsupported reg* data types?

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems to from v10 and thus is missing two reg types.

```
'pg_catalog.regcollation'
'pg_catalog.regnamespace'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of `reg*` types missing in that query. Here is a complete list for v14:

```
\dT pg_catalog.reg*
                        List of data types
   Schema   │     Name      │             Description              
════════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════
 pg_catalog │ regclass      │ registered class
 pg_catalog │ regcollation  │ registered collation
 pg_catalog │ regconfig     │ registered text search configuration
 pg_catalog │ regdictionary │ registered text search dictionary
 pg_catalog │ regnamespace  │ registered namespace
 pg_catalog │ regoper       │ registered operator
 pg_catalog │ regoperator   │ registered operator (with args)
 pg_catalog │ regproc       │ registered procedure
 pg_catalog │ regprocedure  │ registered procedure (with args)
 pg_catalog │ regrole       │ registered role
 pg_catalog │ regtype       │ registered type
(11 rows)
```